# Submit a form with JavaScript when the onchange event of an dropdown is fired

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a dropdown with a submit button, but I would like to eliminate the button, and send the form via Ajax, when the user selects an option from the dropdown.

**Here's the code:**

```
<select name="pin" id="pin"   class="search_box" >
    <option value="">Zip Code</option>

    <?php
    include("conn.php");
    $pin=$_REQUEST[pin];
    $city=$_REQUEST[city];
    $kk="select * from zip order by zip";
    $jj=mysql_query($kk);
    while($mm=mysql_fetch_array($jj))
    {
    ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $mm[zip]?>"<?php if($mm[zip]==$pin){echo "selected";}?>>        
        <?php
            echo $mm[zip]
        ?>    
        </option>

    <?php } ?>

</select>
<input type="button" id="findbutton" name="search_button" value="Go" />
```

Comment: Your code was not visible until I edited. No proof reading and all?

Comment: This is not a PHP question, it's a javascript question. Updated tags.

Comment: So you are saying you want to submit the form on a change in the select rather than on pressing a submit button?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you "on changing"?  The question is ambiguous.

Comment: onchange="document.{formname}.submit();"

Comment: I have tried onchange="this.form.submit(), but it reloads page, rather than utilyzig AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a version using jquery.

```
$('#pin').on('change', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this.form;
  var data = $(form).serialize();
  $ajax({
    data: data,
    url: form[0].action
  })
})
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it reloads the page, rather than utilizing AJAX

Comment: Update my answer using jquery